# How to tell Maven to update manifest's Bundle-Version?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I'm building Eclipse's plugins using Maven, and I'm looking for a way to tell Maven to update the Bundle-Version in the META-INF\MANIFEST.MF file.

The trick is, I need a clean way to do it. So that further colleagues (or even me in some months/years) may not break the final automated build.

Here is what I tried :

---

Using "Bundle-Version: ${project.version}" in the MANIFEST.MF

On a maven point-of-view, this is working.
BUT my Eclipse project is constantly displaying an error : The specified version does not have the correct format (major.minor.micro.qualifier)

---

Using the above but in another META-INF folder (named META-INF-MAVEN) that is used by maven instead of the original :

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>META-INF-MAVEN</directory>
        <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

This is still "working", but the needed duplication of MANIFEST.MF file is far away from what I'm looking for. This is a large trap for future errors, like editing the original MANIFEST.MF file and forgetting the maven one, resulting in a bugged release.

---

Using org.apache.maven.plugins to add the Bundle-Version tag at compile-time from the pom file :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestFile>target/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is the most promising way, BUT it only works if the original MANIFEST.MF **does not have** a Bundle-Version line.
The result is, again, an error within the Eclipse project.

---

And so, here I am, asking for any idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that the `Bundle-Version` must have the correct format (major.minor.micro.qualifier), it won't run properly if this is wrong.

Comment: You should check to use [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) instead of self crafting that...

Answer (score 0):

Following solution finds the `Bundle-Version:` line in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and replaces it with the Maven project version. [replacer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/maven-replacer-plugin/) maven plugin was used for that but there are certainly other maven plugins that can do the same work like [find-and-replace-maven-plugin](https://github.com/floverfelt/find-and-replace-maven-plugin).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>update-manifest-version</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <file>${basedir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</file>
                <regex>true</regex>
                <replacements>
                    <replacement>
                        <token>Bundle-Version: .*</token>
                        <value>Bundle-Version: ${project.artifact.selectedVersion.majorVersion}.${project.artifact.selectedVersion.minorVersion}.${project.artifact.selectedVersion.incrementalVersion}.qualifier
                        </value>
                    </replacement>
                </replacements>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```